# Class definition {get; set;}

Tags: c#

I have a class `Company`.

Inside my class i want to declare a string `LanguageCode` which gets is value from another class `Language`.

Like this:

```
public class Company : Entity  
{    
    public string LanguageCode
     {  
         get
         {
            Language l = new Language();              
            string language = l.Name;
            return language;
         }
         set { ;}
     }
}
```

When running I am not getting any error but is it correct way to create a new instance of a class in get {};

Comment: If the `set` is empty, remove it. It will help user of the class to actually see the property as read-only.

Comment: Do you want to create a new Language instance on every call?

Comment: Do you really need to instantiate a new class every time you get LanguageCode?

Comment: Any why have a property which always returns the same value, regardless of the state of the object?

Comment: Do you want to pass in the `Language` instance (as opposed to creating a new one each time)?

Comment: What are you really asking? This clearly returns a "new instance of a class in get" regardless of current state. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: If language is a characteristics of the company. [e.g. subsidiary in different country will have a different language] then you should pass it to a Company constructor and initialize a string member. so in get you will use this string member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Language object in the constructor

```
public class Company : Entity  
{    
    private Language l;

    public Company()
    {
        l = new Language();  
    }

    public string LanguageCode
    {  
     get
        {
            string language = l.Name;
            return language;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why not `return l.Name;`?

Answer (score 1):

Properties should not have side effects. You normally don't create instances of other classes there and it makes not sense at all anyway in this case. If you need to execute a method to get the value you probably should use a method to return that value instead of a property. Properties should not be "expensive" and if they need to use another method they should be also a method imho.

I assume you store the name of the language in this class and you want to return the `Language` object according to this name:

```
public class Company : Entity
{
    public string LanguageName{ get;set; }

    public Language GetLanguage()
    {
        Language language = new Language(){ Name = this.LanguageName };
        return language;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not very wise. Every time, you call getter, you will get new instance of Language. I believe, that you should declare language instance inside your class.

```
class Company : Entity 
{
   private Language l;

    public Company()
    {
        this.l = new Language();  
    }

   public string LanguageCode
     {  
         get
         {            
            return this.l.Name;
         }         
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good practice, in my opinion, since every time you get the property - the new object is instantiated.

I would create a private property and store the actual string in it:

```
public class Company : Entity  
{   
    private string _languageCode 
    public string LanguageCode
     {  
         get
         {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_languageCode) 
            {
               Language l = new Language();              
               _languageCode = l.Name;
            }
            return _languageCode
         }
     }
}
```

That way the `Language` object will only be created once the property accessed the first time.

Comment: This also can be written: `private Lazy<string> _languageCode = new Lazy<string>(()=> { return new Language().Name; }); public string LanguageCode { get { return _language.Value; } };`

Answer (score 0):

To start, as others have already suggested, if your set is empty then you are better off removing it to make the property clearly read-only.

Then, while it is formally correct, I do not see the logic in this getter. A new class is instantiated every time, and the return value is always the same.

If you just need to return the string with the Language name, you can declare a private property languageCode, initialize it in the constructor and then expose it with a public getter, like this:

```
public class Company : Entity  
{   
    private Language languageCode;

    public Company
    {
        languegeCode = new Language();
    }

    public string LanguageCode
    {  
        get
        {
            return languageCode.Name;
        }
    }
}
```